# Shared context in support directory called for all examples?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec2

I have a shared context in the /spec/support directory. This is called for every example now, not only for those which include it. Is there something special about the support directory and where should I place it if I don't want to run it on every example?

Here is the context-file:

```
require 'spec_helper'

shared_context "timeout context", :timeout do

  around(:each) do |example|
    timeout = example.metadata[:timeout] || 1.second
    Rails.logger.debug "timeout #{timeout} sec for: #{example.metadata[:example_group][:file_path].gsub(/.*?\/spec\//, '')}"
    Timeout::timeout(timeout) {
      example.run
    }
  end

end
```

Is this issue maybe related to the around(:each)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems a little bit like the around block is the culprit, so I added the following to a file in the folder /rspec/support/:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.around(:each) do |example|
    if (example.metadata[:timeout])
      timeout = example.metadata[:timeout] || 1.second
      Rails.logger.debug "timeout #{timeout} sec for: #{example.metadata.full_description}"
      Timeout::timeout(timeout) do
        example.run
      end
    else
      example.run
    end
  end
end
```

and call my specs now with:

```
describe 'explicit timeout of 5 seconds', :timeout => 5.seconds do
end
describe 'implicit timeout of 1 second', :timeout do
end
describe 'no timeout' do
end
```